# GAE: Can I copy an entire app to another identifier?

Tags: google-app-engine

I recall seeing an option on the google app engine admin page that would allow me to duplicate/copy a deployment to a different appid. Was I imagining this? I do have a copy of all the files needed for deployment but I do not currently have access to a computer with admin privileges in order to install the GAE SDK.

Not relevant to this question, but FYI I need to do this simply because there is a major bug that's preventing me from logging in to a particular part of the admin interface and google tech support has failed to resolve the issue, so I'm just trying a workaround.

Comment: Does the answer below answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

Copy old settings to new app via the admin console **admin>application settings>Duplicate Application Settings.** (you'll choose new appid here too)

Then upload a version of your code to the new appId (so you'll need gae sdk or use online sdk [devtable](http://try.devtable.com/)).

Then go to **datastore admin** in the old app, select all the entities and choose **"copy to another app"** You'll need datastore admin to be enabled on the old app (and new app I think).